# CentOS 5.5 automatic shutdowns?

Tags: centos, centos5

I have one server running Windows Server 2003 and another one running CentOS 5.5. I created a proxy to allow users to connect to the CentOS server through the Windows server. Everything worked fine until there were like 30 users online. The CentOS server automatically shut down.

Here is some of the log from file messages:

> Dec  2 01:59:59 localhost avahi-daemon[4596]: Server startup complete. Host name is        localhost.local. Local service cookie is 3442367051.
>   Dec  2 01:59:59 localhost pcscd: winscard.c:304:SCardConnect() Reader E-Gate 0 0 Not Found
>   Dec  2 01:59:59 localhost last message repeated 3 times
>   Dec  2 02:00:00 localhost kernel: mtrr: no more MTRRs available
>   Dec  2 02:00:01 localhost last message repeated 7 times
>   Dec  2 07:08:28 localhost **shutdown[6703]: shutting down for system halt**
>   Dec  2 07:08:28 localhost pcscd: winscard.c:304:SCardConnect() Reader E-Gate 0 0 Not Found
>   Dec  2 07:08:29 localhost smartd[4658]: smartd received signal 15: Terminated 
>   Dec  2 07:08:29 localhost smartd[4658]: smartd is exiting (exit status 0) 
>   Dec  2 07:08:29 localhost avahi-daemon[4596]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
>   Dec  2 07:08:29 localhost avahi-daemon[4596]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::be30:5bff:fee5:c57c.
>   Dec  2 07:08:29 localhost avahi-daemon[4596]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address xxx.xx.xxx.xx.
>   Dec  2 07:11:56 localhost syslogd 1.4.1: restart.

Both servers have more than enough resource for 30 users. What could be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: Looks to me like a clean shutdown, called by the `shutdown` or `halt` command, rather than a crash. Did somebody press the power button, perhaps?

Comment: I don't think so because it works fine with less than 30 users online. Once the number of users reaches 30+ it will shut down in about 10 mins.

Comment: Might be worth having a look at `sar` to see what the load was like before the shutdown. I've honestly not seen a Linux box shut itself down cleanly for no reason... unless it's a temperature/sensors issue.

Comment: I think it is because of my proxy. I just checked it again and noticed that half of the users are disconnected 5 mins before all users are kicked out. Checked twice and it acted the same. Thank you anyways.

Comment: What are you using as a proxy, out of interest?

Comment: I have to implement packet encryption for our server. Since I couldn't do it in CentOS so I had to make a proxy. Does CentOS drop connections if they are 'abnormal'? I have no experince with Linux.